How to read large response using ngx.fetch
I am using nginx with ngx_http_js_module.so
I am using ngx.fetch function works but returns partial response (first around 2k chars) when response body is large. I tried changing buffer_size, max_response_body_size but made no difference.
Also, directives within http and location section but did not help -     js_fetch_max_response_buffer_size 1m;
js_fetch_timeout 60s;
js_fetch_buffer_size 3200k;
Per API, Response.text() - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion; but is returning a partial response.
Here is the code -
var response = await ngx.fetch(service_url,
                                {
                                    body: payload,
                                    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    buffer_size: 102400,
                                    max_response_body_size: 327680000,
                                    verify: false
                                });
var responseText = await response.text();



async function fetch_large_response(r) {
    var service_url = 'http://example.com/api';
    var payload = 'your_payload_data';

    try {
        var response = await ngx.fetch(service_url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: payload,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            buffer_size: 4 * 1024 * 1024,  // 4MB
            max_response_body_size: 10 * 1024 * 1024,  // 10MB
            verify: false
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            r.return(502, 'Bad Gateway');
            return;
        }

        var responseText = await response.text();
        r.return(200, responseText);
    } catch (e) {
        r.return(500, 'Internal Server Error');
    }
}

